# Vue.js / Vuetify: How to remove this huge whitespace in my dialog box?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

My dialog box in our web app renders an empty white-space between the v-cards and the v-card-action buttons (Save and Cancel). What can I do to remove this whitespace / scrollbar?

I tried moving  Cancel/Save to inside of  where  are, but it still leaves a whitespace now below the buttons.

```
 <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="success" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add Student</v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.studnum" label="Student Number"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.surname" label="Surname Name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.fname" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.mname" label="Middle Initial"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>

            </v-container>

          </v-card-text>
           <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save">Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
```

I expect the output to have a smaller dialog box, but now it has whitespaces in the middle.

Images:

Actual output:
https://prnt.sc/nkpvek

https://prnt.sc/nkpvr0

Expected output:
https://prnt.sc/nkpwjk

Thank you !

Comment: your code is correct, i think you're making some extra CSS that enlarges that space, you could check [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYdBoQ?editors=1010)

Comment: What version of vuetify do you use?

Comment: Vuetify is on 2.6.10

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, thank you for your input, I managed to fix it. It turns out, I have a stray CSS code in a separate component that affected it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against putting button inside your dialog as an activator. Messes up CSS sometimes. Place it outside and do

```
@click="dialog = true"
```